# How to subtract two NSDates in Swift?

Tags: swift, nsdate

I've already searched how to do that but the answers didn't work for me, so I'm asking again.
In my app, the user adds a task and a due date. If the due date has passed from the current date, I want to change a label called "pendenciaLbl" (which is in the cell class) to "Late", and the due date label to "Passed due date" so the user knows the due date has been passed. 
The code I'm using to do so is this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("AtivCell") as? AtivCell {


        cell.configureCell(materias[indexPath.row], date: dates[indexPath.row], descricao: descricoes[indexPath.row], pendencia: pendencia[indexPath.row], categoria: categorias[indexPath.row])

        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        let currentDate = NSDate()
        let flags = NSCalendarUnit.Day
        if let transformedDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dates[indexPath.row]) {
        let components = calendar.components(flags, fromDate: transformedDate, toDate: currentDate, options: [])

            if components.day >= 1 {
                dates[indexPath.row] = "Passes due date"
                cell.pendenciaLbl.text = "Late"
                cell.pendenciaLbl.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
            }
        }
        return cell
    } else {
        return AtivCell()
    }
}
```

The thing is that this code isn't working, and I don't know why. I've already tested by adding a date that has already passed (like yesterday) but the labels are still the same. I would appreciate any help.

Important: the dates[indexPath] is in a format of "MMM, dd, yyyy" which means for example February, 29, 2016.

Comment: It may be a good idea to store NSDate objects in your data layer and convert them to NSString only for display - that will simplify data handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An NSDate is really just a Double containing the number of seconds since the Cocoa "epoch date", plus methods. You can use the NSDate instance method timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate to compare 2 dates:

```
let now = NSDate()
let later = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 300)
if later.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate > now.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
{
  print( "later is greater than now")
}
```

It's also quite easy to create an extension to the NSDate class conform to the Equatable and Comparable protocols. If you do that you can use ==, >, <, etc. to compare dates directly.

### Edit:

I see that your dates are stored as strings in "MMM, dd, yyyy" format. In that case you need to set up your date formatter with that format string so it is able to convert them to dates before you can compare them.

A full example might look like this:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM, dd, yyyyy"
if let someDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString("Mar, 02, 2016")
{
  let now = NSDate()

  if someDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate > now.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
  {
    print("someDate is greater than now")
  }
  else
  {
    print("now is >= someDate")
  }
}
else
{
  print("date string \"\(dateString)\" is invalid")
}
```

### Edit #2:

Here is how you extend NSDate so you can compare dates directly using standard inequality expressions to see which is larger/smaller:

```
extension NSDate: Comparable {}

//Define the global operators for the
//Comparable protocol for comparing NSDates

public func <(lhs: NSDate, rhs: NSDate) -> Bool
{
  return lhs.timeIntervalSince1970 < rhs.timeIntervalSince1970
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM, dd, yyyyy"

//The "if let" optional binding will only execute the code if the let 
//statement returns a non-nil value
if let someDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString("Jan, 02, 2016")
{
  let now = NSDate()

  if someDate > now
  {
    print("later is greater than now")
  }
  else
  {
    print("now is >= someDate")
  }
}
else
{
  print("date string \"\(dateString)\" is invalid")
}
```

It looks like Swift 2.0 added the Equatable protocol to the definition of NSDate so you can use `==` to see if 2 dates match exactly. I have no idea why they didn't take the next obvious step and add support for the Comparable protocol "out of the box." Seems absurd not to.

Comment: You can also use laterDate/earlierDate/compare: methods for date coparison

Comment: Yup. There are lots of ways to skin this.

Comment: @DuncanC you only need to define < operator and you can use NSDate method compare. check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34487625/sorting-nsarray-containing-nsdate-objects/34487822#34487822

Comment: @LeoDabus, really? How does that work? Is the compiler able to synthesize all the other inequalities from `<` and the fact that it's Equatable (so `==` is already available)?

Comment: @LeoDabus, I commented on that in my answer. (It seems that was added in Swift 2.0). I'm still surprised and pleased that I only have to provide a definition for `<`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import Foundation

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

let str = "February, 29, 2016"

let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(str) // nil !!!!!

// you HAVE TO SET .dateFormat first!!
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM, dd, yyyy"
let date2 = dateFormatter.dateFromString(str)
```

You didn't set dateFormatter.dateFormat, so your date is always nil