# Double `Comparable` NSDate implementations - test target only

Tags: swift, protocols, quick-nimble

I've implemented `==`, `<`, `>` funcs as `NSDate` extension. The code itself is working well. The problem starts in unit tests, where I use `Quick` & `Nimble` and one of these must also have implemented the given protocol. What can I do now? Protocol is `public`, both the library and my code implements it, so it obviously generates an error.

The error itself: `Redundant conformance of 'NSDate' to protocol 'Comparable'`.

-- edit --
Just a side note to clarify: I cannot remove the implementation in my classes, because I do not want to import `Quick`/`Nimble` in non-test targets.

-- edit --
I'm using Swift 2.2. Comparable code is basically equal to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28109990/849616.

Comment: post your code implementation and Swift version you are using. BTW you don't need to implement == NSDate conforms to Equatable. No need to implement greater than `>`.  Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/34487822/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus I've answered your questions as an edit in the question. The answer you linked does override `>` operator for comparing dates, the same way as I do it. Thanks for side note, but anyway, I'd like to stick firstly with my issue :).